isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition) not returning true while the row is hidden
I have a table that has a filter on col2. I want to get the selected values and print them on a sidebar (html), so the user can copy the ids.
Here is my table setup :
I have my filter, and the 32 first rows are invisible (such as other rows in the rest of the table).

I have this script.gs :
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // return "sheet 10, false"
  Logger.log(sheet.getName(), sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(4))
}

Now, my problem is that the sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(rowIndex) always returns false, while the row n°4 is hidden by my filter.
The documentation does not add more info : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=fr#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition
I couldn't find another script using “isRowHiddenByFilter”.
The code is pretty simple and there are no deprecated tags on the function, so it should work properly. Since I'm using the new table system, I don't know if it's the source of the issue.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand Now, my problem is that the sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(rowIndex) always returns false, while the row n°4 is hidden by my filter.. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output values you expect from your showing image? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

isRowHiddenByFilter only works with filters:

This method doesn't work for filter views and the new group by view.
The workaround is activating the filter from the Google Sheets toolbar or using the dropdown menu in the column header.

function myFunction() {
  const isHidden = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().isRowHiddenByFilter(2);
  Logger.log(isHidden);
}

/**
 * When running the above function it shows true when row 2  
 * is hidden by a filter and false when hidden by a filter view
 */


Hello. This is indeed working. Thanks a lot !
Not related to this function, but do you have any idea why this wouldn't get the proper values when I filter the view ? If I select values "1" and "2" in a column, I'd get other values in the same column.
const range = sheet.getSelection().getActiveRange(); const values = range.getDisplayValues();

@tholeb I'm glad that my answer helps you. Thanks for confirming that. Regarding your follow-up question, please post it as a new question.

function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Your sheet');

  // return "sheet 10, false"
  Logger.log(sheet.getName(), sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(4))
}

You can use method getSheetByName()

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
